# PhoneGap with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, twitter

I finally found a nice mobile UI called Twitter Bootstrap. I know it's popular. It's not loading into PhoneGap. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: And how do you expect it should be loaded?

Comment: Phonegap has all kinds of issues with compatibility because it relies on the phone's default browser to render. I am instead using Mobile Angular JS and building an HTML5 web app.

Comment: It's just that you did not specify what and how have you tried to load it. No story-telling description of the problem, no errors and a simple question which leads nowhere.

Comment: It does appear that bootstrap in (now) Cordova does not work quite right (even now over a year later).  I've been battling trying to get a modal to work for some time now.